# How to log ping/pong message with Spring websocket?

Tags: websocket, ping, spring-ws

I'm trying to check and log the ping / pong exchanges between the client and Spring Websocket server.

I tried to extend **BinaryWebSocketHandler** and add this method:

```
@Override
protected void handlePongMessage(WebSocketSession session, PongMessage message) throws Exception {
    log.trace("RECEIVING PONG {} {}",message.getPayloadLength(), Utils.bytesToHex(message.getPayload().array()));
    super.handlePongMessage(session, message);
}

@Override
protected void handleBinaryMessage(WebSocketSession session, BinaryMessage message) throws Exception {
    log.trace("RECEIVING MSG {} {}",message.getPayloadLength(), Utils.bytesToHex(message.getPayload().array()));
}
```

I can see handleBinaryMessage logs, but I cannot see PONG log. Do you know why? Is it possibile ping/pong is not enabled?

Answer (score 1):

The handlePongMessage() method gets called when a pong message is received, not when a ping message is received. This is not necessarily what you'd expect.

The way I tested this was using wscat.

```
% npm install -g wscat 
% wscat -c ws://localhost:8080/ws_endpoint --slash -P
> Connected (press CTRL+C to quit)
> /ping hi
> < Received pong (data: "hi")
> /pong
Trace message logged.
```

So the client has to send a pong, not a ping!

Comment: Thanks Chris, so there is not method to check or control the ping sending from Spring?

Comment: Hi Tobia, yes, it is odd that there's no handlePingMessage. I guess not many people use the ping/pong messages and therefore this functionality has been neglected.

Comment: I think there is no other way to detect client disconnection, this is why I need to check or control ping/pong. Finally I had to create a scheduler and send ping message from server, then I start receiving handlePongMessage trace. Thanks for your help